# getting the following error while accesing python

Tags: python-3.x

getting the following error while accesing python

```
from collections import Counter
alphas = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
res = ''
for char in alphas:
    res = "{0},{1}|{2}".format(res , char, Counter[char])
    print(res)
```

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Counter is a constructor, not a sequence... plus what is the point of counting a single character one by one in a list? Code doesn't make sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to achieve counting characters alone for eg a|23,b|56,...z|12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Counter it is a lot easier than what you are trying to achieve:

```
from collections import Counter

alphas = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
print(Counter(alphas))
```

And if you want to print them in format of "count|letter" then:

```
res = ''
counts = Counter(alphas)
for count, letter in counts.items():
    res += '{}|{},'.format(count, letter)

print(res)
```

Comment: for count, letter in alphas.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: @praveena sorry mate, I didn't check the code, didn't notice the mistake/semi-typo, but I guess you figured it out now.

Comment: This doesn't actually explain from where the original error originated.

Comment: @SethMMorton, the original error originated from him/her trying to invoke a function using square brackets and ... functions are objects as everything in python and the resulting error. I don't think the actual goal was to understand the error, but to get the "program" to work.

Comment: @AlekseiMaide Yes, I know that.  The point is that this answer is only half useful. It does direct the OP in how to do what they actually want, but it does not prevent them from making the same original mistake again, nor give them more insight into Python's object model.

Comment: @SethMMorton I guess there is room for improvement, will put some thought into it, but i guess the question should be renamed as well, as it's not very descriptive for the future readers.